# Distributed scaling layer (NodeJS based) over LMDB key store

Tags: javascript, node.js, key-value-store

I am looking for an open source Scalabale-ACID based, Key-Value data store, written in NodeJS.

In my quest to find scalable ACID key-value store,I have considered Foundation DB and Apache Ignite, however they seems to not meet my other criterias.

1. Foundation DB was rejected because of its minimum 4GB RAM requirement for each node.
2. Apache Ignite was rejected becasue it has no NodeJS binding which supports ACID.

Considered and googled many other products, but none seems to meet this **NodeJS-SmallFootPrint-BalzinglyFast-KeyValue-StorageEngine** thing all at once.

Then we come across LMDB, but not able to find any scalable layer over it. Now before I create it from scratch, wanted to know if any one has created any such layer over it.

I am looking for an Open Source distributed Horizontally scalalable ACID layer over legendary LMDB (Lightning memory DB). The goal is to create custom DB api over this key-value storage engine.

Its not that I am fixed to LMDB, but if any ACID-Scalable-KeyValue storage engine with Node js binding is present, I am open for that solution too. (**Range search is a must have feature of our final product**).